# Is it possible to provide a new instance of a dependency for each parent in Angular?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, service

Is it possible to provide a new instance of a dependency for each parent? I'm trying to create a composer directive which increments the counter in provided service if another instance of composer directive is it's child so I can host bind the class accordingly.

```html
<div composer> <!-- 1 - parent -->
    ...
    <div composer> <!-- 2 - child -->
        ...
        <div composer></div> <!-- 3 - grandchild -->
    </div>
    ...
</div>

<!-- Resets counter since this composer is root -->
<div composer> <!-- 1 - parent -->
...
</div>
```

Here is the stack blitz I've created, I've looked into hierarchical injectors but I'm suspecting that this may not be possible to create a new instance per parent element
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g9rwvu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomposer%2Fcomposer.directive.ts

If I pass the service in providers, a new instance of service is being created for each directive, but I would like to get a new instance only for the parent/root composer directive.

In short, what I'm trying to do is something similar to React's useContext hook where I can pass context along children & set new context when a new parent component is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented this one with the help of hierarchical injectors. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xml2kq . basically you can inject another instance of a directive, if it is already in the tree, and increment your level.

```
constructor(@SkipSelf() @Optional() protected parent: Composer) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.$level = this.parent ? this.parent.$level + 1 : 1;
}
```

if you need to access some field of the component in the template, you can use `exportAs: 'someName'` and then `#tplVar="someName"`. with such piece of code, you can then reference the directive instance with the help of `tplVar`.

And if you need an answer to the "title question". it is possible to provide instance of a service for every instance of a directive. just mention it in the directive's `providers`, not in the ngModule's ones

Comment: Thanks @Andrei, that is exactly the functionality I was trying to implement!